# How to fix errors when installing varbase with Composer?

Tags: composer

I'm using Drupal 8 and I'm trying to install the varbase distribution from the command line, on Windows with Acquia Dev Desktop.

The steps I did are:

- Disable opcache
- Check `composer -V  >>> result`
- Run `composer create-project Vardot/varbase-build:^8.4.06 %1 --no-dev --ignore-platform-reqs`

This is causing the following error:

> - Installing vardot/varbase (8.4.06): Downloading (100%)
>     Writing lock file
>     Generating autoload files
>     PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\www\tmp_var\vendor\drupal-composer\drupal-scaffold\src\PrestissimoFileFetcher.php on line 34
>     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\www\tmp_var\vendor\drupal-composer\drupal-scaffold\src\PrestissimoFileFetcher.php on line 34

I installed composor on windows Url:
https://getcomposer.org/download/

(This is besided the compososer which is included in Acuia Desktop Version 2)

```
C:\www>composer self-update
You are already using composer version 1.5.1 (stable channel).
```

Then I exectuted commando:

```
composer create-project Vardot/varbase-project:^8.4.07 varbaseyellowbird --no-dev >> installlog.txt
```

After running it my project drupal folder was not looking good so I runned it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 8 requires PHP 5.5.9 or greater. The error is informing you that you have a lower version than that installed; specifically that the functionality for obtaining class name using `::class`, which was added in 5.5, is missing.

The solution is to upgrade PHP to a version that Drupal supports.

Comment: In acuqia desktop, php 5.6.30 is included....

Comment: ok running php.exe response indeed with low version.

Comment: What VM/Acquia/etc has, vs what the CLI uses can be two different things. For Windows, you might want to swap out to DrupalVM, which currently supports up to 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP** must be **5.6**

**Warning:** About composer

https://getcomposer.org/download/

As we dedicated that composer had 3 changes updates under 10 days

1.5.1 (2017-08-09)
1.5.0 (2017-08-08)
1.4.3 (2017-08-06)
1.4.2 (2017-05-17)
1.4.1 (2017-03-10)

Which composer version are you using?!

After updating the composer:

```
   $ sudo composer self-update 1.5.1
```

You could use:

```
$ composer create-project Vardot/varbase-project:^8.4.06 PROJECT_DIR_NAME --no-dev --no-interaction
```

or

```
$ composer create-project Vardot/varbase-project:^8.4.07 PROJECT_DIR_NAME --no-dev --no-interaction
```

As we started to use Vardot/varbase-project from varbase 8.4.06

To read more https://www.drupal.org/node/2903606

Comment: I installled composer in windows besided acquia desktop. I updated the question.... I still not gettting varbase to run...

Comment: @rajabnatshah composer is skipping the varbase patches. I am using composer 1.9 and php 7.1